# Excel VBA Runtime Error

Tags: vba, excel

new to excel vba and the code gives run time error 1004 , application defined or object defined error.

```
Dim rowCount As Integer
Dim currentRow As Integer
Dim switchAmount As Integer
Dim switchRef As Integer
Dim switchAccnt As Integer
Dim cbsAmount As Integer
Dim cbsRef As Integer
Dim cbsAccnt As Integer
Dim checker As Integer
Dim cbsCheck As Integer
Dim cbsRow As Integer
Dim cbsRow2 As Integer
Dim currentRow2 As Integer
Dim checker2 As Integer

Sub main()
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    checker = 0
    currentRow = 2
    switchAccnt = 2
    switchRef = 3
    switchAmount = 4
    cbsAmount = 6
    cbsRef = 7
    cbsAccnt = 8
    MsgBox checker
    Do While currentRow <= rowCount
        If currentRow Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Call switch_call_over(currentRow, switchAccnt, _
                switchRef, switchAmount, cbsAccnt, cbsRef, cbsAmount)
        End If
        currntRow = currentRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Sub switch_call_over(cRow As Integer, sAccnt As Integer, sRef As Integer, _
  sAmount As Integer, cAccnt As Integer, cRef As Integer, cAmount As Integer)
    Do While switchRow <= rowCount
        checker = 0
        ''''error is given when this line ia runned''''
        If Cells(cRow, cAmount) = Cells(switchRow, sAmount) Then
            checker = checker + 3
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: a) [edit] your question, select your code and tap ctrl+K. b) tell us what line of code the error occurs on. c) supply the values of any variants relative to the error.

Comment: btw, just because Integer sound kuh-ool, there is no reason to ever use it. A Long is actually a Long Integer and should be used in all cases of declaring a var that is to accept a whole number (without fraction or decimal component).

Comment: thw problem is the sub being called doesnt qualify WHAT cells and WHERE. Application defined error sometimes means you "Arent in line with the object model." Plainly stating Cells doesnt help the compiler that much. Which cells? Those in the worksheet on your coworkers personal drive? Sorry Im being a bit silly but you understand.

Comment: I fixed your spacing and indentation, it's much easier to read now, but with your lack of explanation I'm unable to help except pointing out that the last line says `End Sup`, and also even with that long list of "unnecessary" variables, you still have not declared all the variables you're using.  I'd suggest putting `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always], to help "force" you to properly declare and handle your variables. If you need more help, you'll need to give a lot more info. See [ask] and **[mcve]** and [also this](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk//writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: `currntRow = currentRow + 1` another vote for `Option Explicit`

Comment: Anyone who says "use `Option Explicit`" gets an automatic +1 from me!

Comment: switchRow=0 you cant have a row 0

Answer (score 3):

Your problems would be made so much clearer if you used `Option Explicit` at the top of every module.  You can even set this as a default mode when you create new modules.

(I picked the following up this morning: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CprZ1.gif)
[image]

If you had set `Option Explicit` then Excel would have given you a more specific error message.

The answer is simple: You have not declared or initiated `switchRow`, which means, when used as a `Integer`/`Long` will be set with a default value of `0` (don't let the fact that it is actually a `Variant` confuse you at this point in time!).

The `Cells()` parameters require positive values, so `Cells(0, sAmount)` will fail. As you have seen.

Of course, the rest of your code has many issues, not the least the infinite loop you have set up!